# How to omit checkbox from select-all event in Backrid.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

In my collection there are models which I would like to exclude from being selected. Is there a way to make a checkbox non responsive to select-all event? I would like it to stay `checked` and `disabled`. I've tried to do it outside of the Backgrid:

```
        @$el.find("tr.inactive")
        .find(":checkbox")
        .prop("disabled", true)
        .prop("checked", true)
```

But it's overridden on each `"backgrid:select-all"` event.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to select all of them and then filter by the one you don't want to select. This happens a lot in sql. Something like:

```
.filter(function( index ) {
  return !index === 'whateverSelector';
})
```